What's the two-dimentional lock-in technique for STM topograph?
I have STM topograph data. I want to use the Lawler-Fujita algorithm to correct its drift, so I need its phase. I learned that the 2D lock-in technique can be used to acquire the phase of $T(r)$, but I can't find any more detailed information

Consider to spell out acronyms.
